# Population pyramid plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, population

I am new to R and trying to create a population pyramid plot similar to the first one here https://klein.uk/teaching/viz/datavis-pyramids/. I have a dataset with two variables sex and age groups that looks like this:

```
   sex       age_group

1   Male      20-30
2   Female    50-60
3   Male      70-80
4   Male      10-20
5   Female    80-90
...   ...       ...
```

This is the code I used

```
ggplot(data = pyramid_graph(x = age_group, fill = sex)) +
geom_bar(data = subset(pyramid_graph, sex == "F")) + 
geom_bar(data = subset(pyramid_graph, sex == "M")) + 
mapping = aes(y = - ..count.. ),
position = "identity") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = abs) +
coord_flip()
```

I do not get any errors from R but when I execute this code a blank image is produced.

Can anyone help?
Thank you

Comment: Hello Clarissa, welcome to SO.  You maximise your chances of getting a useful answer if you post a minimal reproducible example.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Specifically you need to include your input data.    For a start, your input dataset needs at least THREE variables: age group, sex, and the value to plot.  Secondly, I suspect you have an unmatched closing bracket in your `position="identity")`  Thirdly, make `fill=sex` an aesthetic and use only one `geom_bar` with appropriate changes to the `mapping`.

Comment: There are specialised packages for population pyramids, such as the aptly-named __pyramid__ package.

Answer (score 1):

Using a similar input dataset from the same website that you cite in your question:

```
# Obtain source data
load(url("http://klein.uk/R/Viz/popGH.RData"))
# Convert to summary table
df <- as_tibble(popGH) %>% 
        mutate(AgeDecade=as.factor(floor(AGE/10)*10)) %>% 
        group_by(SEX, AgeDecade) %>% 
        dplyr::summarise(N=n(), .groups="drop") %>% 
        # A more transparent way of managing the transformation to get "Females to the left".
        mutate(PlotN=ifelse(SEX=="Female", -N, N)) 
# Create the plot
df %>% ggplot() +
   geom_col(aes(fill=SEX, x=AgeDecade, y=PlotN)) +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-2*10**5, 0, 2*10**5), labels=c("200k", "0", "200k")) +
   labs(y="Population", x="Age group") +
   scale_fill_discrete(name="Sex") +
   coord_flip()
```

Gives

[image]

Note that I've created a new column to create the "females to the left" effect in the plot.  Normally, I'd avoid doing that and would rely on the options to the various `ggplot` functions to achieve the same thing (much as you have attempted to do).  However, in this case, I think it's far more transparent (and simple) use the extra column rather than to modify the `mapping`.